# Instantiating object from class type in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to understand someone else's code and it isn't making sense to me to me how it seems like the code is instantiating an object from the class type:

```
[KZNNodeType registerType:name inputs:@{ @"Image" : CIImage.class } outputs:@{ @"Output" : CIImage.class } processingBlock:^(id node, NSDictionary *inputs, NSMutableDictionary *outputs)
    {
        //processing Block definition
        CIImage *image = inputs[@"Image"];
          if (!image) {
            return;
          }

        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName
                                   keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, nil];
        CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
        outputs[@"Output"] = outputImage;
    }
     ];
```

In the above the "inputs" parameter passed is a dictionary with one item "Image" : CIImage.class

then it looks like an object is being instantiated with the line:

```
CIImage *image = inputs[@"Image"];
```

If I try this:

```
CIImage * image = CIImage.class
```

I get a warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CIImage *' with an expression of type 'Class'"

Can anyone shed light?

Per the answer I decided to show the overloaded versions of registerType.  I nearly went cross-eyed trying to make sense of them.  It seems like the author was purposefully trying to make it hard to follow (I added what comments and indentation there is)  Is it just my opinion or is this code needlessly convoluted???:

```
+ (KZNNodeType *)registerType:(NSString *)typeName inputs:(NSDictionary *)inputs outputs:(NSDictionary *)outputs processingBlock:(void (^)(id, NSDictionary *, NSMutableDictionary *))processingBlock
{
  //call more specialized registerType adding Class parameter
    return [self registerType:typeName withClass:KZNNode.class inputs:inputs outputs:outputs processingBlock:processingBlock];
}

+ (KZNNodeType *)registerType:(NSString *)typeName withClass:(Class)nodeClass inputs:(NSDictionary *)inputs outputs:(NSDictionary *)outputs processingBlock:(void (^)(id node, NSDictionary *inputs, NSMutableDictionary *outputs))processingBlock
{
  //call even more specialized registerType with a closure/block that assigns to the type the captured variables
    return [self registerType:typeName withBuilder:^(KZNNodeType *type)
    {
        type.baseNodeClass = nodeClass;
        [inputs enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id, id, BOOL *))^(NSString *name, Class dataType, BOOL *stop) {
          // If the block sets *stop to YES, the enumeration stops.
            [type addSocket:KZNNodeSocketTypeInput name:name type:dataType];
        }];

        [outputs enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id, id, BOOL *))^(NSString *name, Class dataType, BOOL *stop) {
          [type addSocket:KZNNodeSocketTypeOutput name:name type:dataType];
    }];

    type.processingBlock = processingBlock;
  }];
}
```

Then the processing block gets called in this method:

```
- (NSDictionary *)evaluateWithTick:(NSUInteger)tick withForwardPropagation:(BOOL)forwardPropagation
{
  if (tick != self.evaluationTick) {
    self.evaluationTick = tick;
    NSMutableDictionary *evaluation = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [self.inputSockets enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(KZNSocket *socket, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      NSDictionary *result = [socket.sourceSocket.parent evaluateWithTick:tick withForwardPropagation:NO];
      id socketValue = result[socket.sourceSocket.name];
      if (socketValue) {
        evaluation[socket.name] = socketValue;
      }
    }];

    NSMutableDictionary *evaluationOutput = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    void (^processingBlock)(id, NSDictionary *, NSMutableDictionary *) = [(id)self.type performSelector:@selector(processingBlock)];
    processingBlock(self, evaluation, evaluationOutput);
    self.evaluationResults = evaluationOutput;

    if (forwardPropagation) {
      [self.outputSockets enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(KZNSocket *socket, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [socket.connections enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(KZNSocket *connectedSocket, BOOL *stop) {
          [connectedSocket.parent evaluateWithTick:tick withForwardPropagation:forwardPropagation];
        }];
      }];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inputs:@{ @"Image" : CIImage.class }` argument of the method and the `NSDictionary *inputs` argument of the block are not the same `inputs` dictionary.

```
[KZNNodeType registerType:name
    inputs:@{ @"Image" : CIImage.class }    // argument of [[KZNNodeType registerType:inputs:outputs:processingBlock:]
    outputs:@{ @"Output" : CIImage.class }
    processingBlock:^(id node, NSDictionary *inputs, NSMutableDictionary *outputs) {
        //processing Block definition
        CIImage *image = inputs[@"Image"];  // inputs argument of the block, inputs[@"Image"] returns a CIImage*
        if (!image) {
            return;
        }
        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, image, nil];
        CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
        outputs[@"Output"] = outputImage;
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  I added the overloaded versions of this method into my OP.  I'd be interested in your opinion of the code.  To me it seems almost purposefully convoluted.

Comment: I think it's a coding style: blocks instead of classes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

`CIImage *image = inputs[@"Image"];` defines `image` to be a pointer to an *instance* of `CIImage`, but you've assigned a pointer to the `CIImage` class to that variable.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought.  So you are saying it is wrong, correct?  Xcode won't warn because it is returned from a dictionary and doesn't know what type it is, agree?

Comment: Right.   You can use the generics syntax to make the dictionary typing more explicitly.   `NSDictionary<NSString *, CIImage *>*` IIRC.